# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

Boas estou a ter um erro no meu javascript alguem pode ajudar?

```
'<a id="showData" onclick="OpenDescriptionModal(\''+ postData[0].replace('#', '') + '\', \'' + editTitle + '\', \''+ description.replace(/"/g, '\'') +'\');" class="btn btn-success" title="View" lang="en" style="margin-top: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-eye iconInsideBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>View</span></a><a style="margin-left: 1em; margin-top: 5px;" onclick="openEditModal(\''+ postData[0].replace('#', '') + '\', \'' + editTitle + '\', \''+ description.replace(/"/g, '\'') +'\');" class="btn btn-success" title="Edit" lang="en"><i class="fa fa-edit iconInsideBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i><span lang="en">Edit</span></a><a style="margin-left: 1em; margin-top: 5px;" onclick="openDeleteModal(\''+ postData[0].replace('#', '') +'\');" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" lang="en"><i class="fa fa-times-circle iconInsideBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i><span lang="en">Delete</span></a>'
```

Comment: O que tem em `postData`, `editTitle` e `description`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura sao as variáveis que tem o id, o titulo, e a description de uma tabela.

Comment: Eu sei, cara; quero saber o conteúdo [facepalm]

Comment: @MarceloUchimura xD o id é um int, o titulo uma string vindo de um input, e o description tras codigo html, visto eu estar a usar o Quill Rich text editor, e este me passar tudo o que é guardado, em html.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

Comment: @hkotsubo tanto quanto vejo estou a concatenar tudo, mas pode me estar a passar algo.

Answer (score 0):

Troca todo

```
description.replace(/"/g, '\'')
```

por

```
description.replace(/["']/g, '\\\'')
```

que teu couro estará a são e salvo e poderás dormir o sono de Morfeu.

Comment: Como nenhuma amostra de conteúdo das variáveis foi fornecida, usa esta sugestão por tua conta e risco.

Comment: Ahaha muito obrigado! Funcionou! Pode me explicar o porque desta forma funcionar? Qual a diferença?

Comment: A diferença é que eu escrevi `description.replace(/["']/g, '\\\'')` e tu escreveste `description.replace(/"/g, '\'')`. Gostaste da minha explicação, príncipe dos cavaleiros alados? :D

Comment: Não foi necessária essa parte mas sim em vez de ter apenas uma \' pus as tres \\\', isso resolveu logo o meu problema.

Comment: Experimenta meter uma `'` em `description` e terás uma supresa desagradável